# unexpected *, unexpected (

Tags: c, oop, header-files, netbeans-7

I'm trying to following to application in [OOP C](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf) but I get errors in my new.h file.

I am getting a bunch of "unexpected" errors.
Just about everything after the first 'void' is exepected.
Any ideas?

```
#ifndef NEW_H
#define NEW_H

#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void * new (const void * type);
void delete (void * item);  


#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif



#endif  /* NEW_H */
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you're compiling for C? `new` and `delete` are C++ keywords and it looks like that's what it's barfing on.

Comment: Are you trying to implement the `new` and `delete` operators? If so, you should add the `operator` keyword.

Comment: what exactly is OOP C? C is not object oriented.

Comment: @fayyazkl But you can implement OOP concepts in C.

Comment: Some but not all. There are obvious limitations. And i doubt that was the intention when it was mentioned in question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to simulate the functionality of `new` in `C` as it in `C++` then you are actually given wrong argument of `new`.
It should be `const unsigned int` or `const size_t` 
because new is used in C++ as

```
int *p;
p=new (sizeof(int));
```

But here it's type mismatch can't convert `int` to `const void *`

For `delete` it's fine because `delete` takes `pointer` as argument

Comment: Problem here is compilation with new as a function name using c code and gcc

Comment: Somehow compiler know about the keyword new then only it gives error.Are you using built-in IDE or separate compiler and editor

Comment: Because in my case it's not giving any error in  Linux gcc-4.5

Comment: Well neither is mine. And i asked the questioner the same one

Comment: Ohh Sorry I didn't see the name and I thought you are the person who asked this.... sorry man

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be one of the few C programs which are not valid under C++: the identifiers `new` and `delete` are perfectly valid under C, but are reserved under C++.

Answer (score 1):

Well you're compiling as C, but the `new` and `delete` operators are only supported in C++.

Also, the signature for `new` and `delete` are:

```
void* operator new(size_t n);
void operator delete(void* p);
```

You can also overload these operators for specific classes (by declaring them inside a class).

Comment: I think the opposite is true.

Comment: In this example , new and delete are being defined as new methods.

Comment: There's also placement `new`, and array `new`, and ... a number of other variations on `new`.

Answer (score 1):

new and delete are keywords in C++, not legal function names.

Even if you think you are compiling C, test if this fixes it. If it does not, then it may be the classic C/C++ mysterious error: problem is in the *previous* include, it is probably missing a semicolon or something.

Comment: This is a c program not a C++ program

Comment: Is your file extension .c? Are you compiling this with a c compiler or a c++ compiler?

Comment: @fayyazkl yes it is a .c file. I'm using gcc to try and compile it.

Comment: Then add #error in the #ifdef. If compiler falls on that, it means it is compiling C++ for some reason.

Comment: @Rufio There is something wrong with your setup. I just verified by even defining the function new and called it in your above code. .c file compiled with gcc and it worked fine. How are you using gcc? from and IDE or commandline? If IDE try the command line OR check if you IDE is using g++ at the back or something.

Comment: @fayyazkl I tried both ways, still the same result. I have gcc from MingW